# Multiple tuples in Python

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist

If I have multiple tuples, how can I calculate the sum of a non prime number from each tuple while ignoring the strings and then add them to a new list:

Example:
From these tuples:

```
("Hi", 1, 2, 3)
()
(5, 20, "python", "!") 
(7, "java")
```

I would get: `[6, 0, 25]` because:

`("Hi", 1, 2, 3)` would give `1+2+3 = 6`,
`()` would give `0` ,
`(5, 20, "python", "!")` would give `5+20 = 25`,
`(7, "java")` would give `7` which is not kept because it is a prime number

Thanks

Comment: I edited your question to make things more readable and clear. Modify it again if the statement about the `7` being prime is not accurate.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use `isinstance(n, int)` to check that a number is an integer
2. Write a simple primality checking function (e.g test if the number is divisible by the integers from 2 up to its square root)
3. Write a function to filter out any numbers that don't conform to the above tests, and sum the rest
4. Use a loop or a list comprehension to apply the function to your tuples and put them in a list

So in the end you'll have something like this (assuming you can write a primality checker; I'm sure there are plenty others on this website if you need more help with that):

```
def sum_nonprimes(seq):
    return sum(n for n in seq if isinstance(n, int) and not is_prime(n))

[sum_nonprimes(tup) for tup in tuple_list]
```

The expression inside *sum* is a generator expression; it's a concise way of generating the n's in the sequence that satisfy the conditional. If you don't like this syntax, there are other ways of doing this, including using the `filter()` function or a simple for loop.